# Blackberry webworks www directory reset when build & install?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks

First i have configure all software like BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 2.2 and BlackBerry 10.3.1 Simulator.

Then after i have implemented app project into www folder.

When i click on "build & install" button into Blackberry webworks at that time www folder reboot(reset www directory)

Comment: Put your project code into root www folder(NOTE : Plz don't change into blackberry 10 www folder). then after "build & install"